# Cannot connect to Elasticearch with Java API (in Scala)

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

So I am trying to connect to an ElasticSearch cluster, following these examples:

1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html
2. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html

This is my code:

```
def saveToES(message: String) {

    println("start saving")
    //    val client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("xxx.com"), 9200))

    // prepare Adresses
    val c = InetAddress.getByName("xxx.com")
    println("inetadress done")
    val d = new InetSocketTransportAddress(c, 9200)
    println("socketadress done")

    val settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "CLUSTER").build();
    println("settings created")
    val a = TransportClient.builder()
    println("Builder created")
    val aa = a.settings(settings)
    println("settings set")
    val b = a.build
    println("client built")
    val client = b.addTransportAddress(d)
    println("adress added to client")
    val response = client.prepareIndex("performance_logs", "performance").setSource(message).get()
    //      
    println(response.toString)
    //
    //    // on shutdown
    //
    //    client.close();
}
```

And the program get's stuck on building the  client (val b = a.build), so my last print is ("settings set"). No error or whatever, just stuck. For firewall reasons I have to deploy the whole thing in a jar and execute on a server, so I can't really debug with the IDE.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Shouldnt it be a.build()?

Comment: Please try to use port 9300 instead of 9200.

Comment: @alpert It's in Scala, you can leave the paranthesesis

Comment: @Michael 9200 is correct, but the code doesn't even execute to that point where the adress is added